# Steam installer will not launch after upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: steam

I have just completed an upgrade of Ubuntu to the latest LTS version, and decided I would try Steam for Linux.  I downloaded the .deb package and tried to install it.

The package opens the new Software Centre, but when I click install, it simply stalls out (the button turns orange briefly).

All the latest stable drivers are installed and working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install it with via Terminal.

Open Unity Dash and find Terminal application, run it.

Download steam deb file:

`wget -O ~/steam.deb https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb`

Then, run this command to install it:

`sudo dpkg -i ~/steam.deb`

It will ask you for your account password (you won't see it as you typing)

If there will be some errors, run `sudo apt-get install -f` to install missing packages and then steam will be installed automatically. Then just run Steam from Unity Dash or via Terminal: `steam`.

Comment: Can you elaborate and explain what this does? OP might not know.

Comment: @grooveplex ok, I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you for your help, this solved my problem.